# is Alexa count web service request to the site for ranking?

Tags: android, ios, web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have a site that i implement alexa ranking for it , for that site i have android and ios software ,because half of trafic of my site goes to the android and ios softeare , i want alexa count that trafic but idon't now how can do this . Now my question is :

> is Alexa count web service request to the site for ranking  ?

And if the answer is no , do we have alternate way to alexa count web service request to the my site ? (sorry for my language )

Answer (score 2):

its depends on your implementation if you using web view in your app, and when javascript is enabled, yes it is

but if you just using Webservice in premium service, maybe it counts

Answer (score 1):

**Quoting from Alexa wikipedia page which explains how Alexa rank sites:**

Alexa ranks sites based primarily on tracking a sample set of Internet traffic users of its toolbar for the Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome web browsers.The Alexa Toolbar includes a popup blocker, a search box, links to Amazon.com and the Alexa homepage, and the Alexa ranking of the site that the user is visiting. It also allows the user to rate the site and view links to external, relevant sites.

So this means there is no need to register your site for Alexa. They get their data from variety of sources.